# How to reuse memory pointer of GDAL Memory driver

Tags: gdal, c++, memory

I am doing the same as in [[GDAL API]: can't save image in some formats](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134000/gdal-api-cant-save-image-in-some-formats)

That is, saving a `JPEG` image with `GDAL`. I know I'd have to create a `MEM` buffer and then `CreateCopy` to `JPEG`. However, I'd like to avoid the allocation of two buffers since my image might be big and I use my own memory buffer.

Is there a way to pass the data memory address that I'd like to use to the MEM driver?

I've seen this mysterious article http://www.gdal.org/frmt_mem.html which references the `DATAPOINTER` option. I've seen another reference [here](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2006-November/010583.html)
which does

```
sprintf(filename,"MEM:::DATAPOINTER=%d,PIXELS=%d,LINES=%d,BANDS=1,DATATYPE=%d,PIXELOFFSET=0,LINEOFFSET=0,BANDOFFSET=0",datpt,pixels,lines,datatype);
dataset = GDALOpen(filename,GA_Update);
```

How would this translate to c++? Maybe

```
    papszOptions = CSLSetNameValue( papszOptions, "DATAPOINTER", datapointer );
```

and so on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was resolved in the gdal-dev mailing list, here's how:

1. create the [MEM driver](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_mem.html) and create the mem image with 0 bands
2. Get the pointer to your allocated memory with [CPLPrintPointer](https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/frmts/vrt/vrtdriver.cpp)
3. Use `AddBand` from the dataset to add the bands

e.g. (error checking omitted)

```
unsigned int numbands = 0;
char **papszOptions = NULL;
GDALDriver *poDriver  = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName("MEM");

GDALDataset* poDstDS = poDriver->Create( "dummyname",(int)width, (int)height, numbands, GDT_Byte, papszOptions);

for(unsigned int b = 0; b < 3; b++)
{
    char szPtrValue[128] = { '\0' };
    int nRet = CPLPrintPointer( szPtrValue,
                                reinterpret_cast<void*>(abyRasters[b]),
                                sizeof(szPtrValue) );
    szPtrValue[nRet] = 0;
    papszOptions = CSLSetNameValue(papszOptions,
                                   "DATAPOINTER", szPtrValue);
    poDstDS->AddBand(GDT_Byte, papszOptions);
}
CSLDestroy(papszOptions);

//jpeg write test:
{
    char **papszOptions2 = NULL;
    papszOptions2 = CSLSetNameValue( papszOptions2, "QUALITY", "40" );
    GDALDriver* jpegDriver = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName("JPEG");
    GDALDataset* jpeg_ds = jpegDriver->CreateCopy("somename.jpg", poDstDS, false, papszOptions2, GDALDummyProgress, NULL);
    CSLDestroy(papszOptions2);
    GDALClose( (GDALDatasetH) jpeg_ds );
}

GDALClose( (GDALDatasetH) poDstDS );
```